# Rollback Spring JDBC operation when not in transaction

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, spring-transactions

I am using annotation driven transaction management with Spring JDBC.

I would like to have Spring throw an exception when by mistake I forgot to annotate with @Transactional a service method that inserts/updates/deletes.

By default data can be inserted/updated/deleted even not within a transaction.

Comment: You can use Propagation.MANDATORY in your DAO layer

Comment: It was chosen to use the @Transactional only on the service layer since transactions start always from there.

Comment: Well you can iterate over all service classes via reflection and check if all of them contain @Transactional annotation

Comment: Propagation.MANDATORY won't start a transaction if there is none; it'll just throw an error.

Comment: All the replies about `Propagation.MANDATORY` is correct, but always consider about testing through JUnit to confirm any expected behaviour

Comment: @sam_eera Please provide your comment as an answer so I can select it as solution. As there was no other alternative, it was implemented as you suggested and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Propagation.MANDATORY` in your DAO layer.

`Propagation.MANDATORY` will not start a transaction. It will check whether perticular method is attached to a transaction or not, if not container will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation (Spring docs) it's just metadata to give an indication that the method or interface can be configured by something that is 'transactionally aware' (ie

With just tx:annotation-driven and no @Transactional attributes I believe you get the "default" transactionality applied:

> Propagation setting is REQUIRED.
>   Isolation level is DEFAULT.
>   Transaction is read/write.
>   Transaction timeout defaults to the default timeout of the underlying transaction system, or none if timeouts are not supported.
>   ny RuntimeException triggers rollback, and any checked Exception does not.
>   Assuming you're using the tx:annotation to drive it via a transaction manager then missing out the @Transactional attribute means you can't apply such properties as readOnly, isolation, propagation,rollbackFor, noRollbackFor etc.

I believe that MVC is slightly different - the hibernate session is tied directly to the MVC request - ie when the request is received the transaction starts.

Back to your example, the code for getSession() in HibernateDAOSupport is as follows:

```
protected final Session getSession()
    throws DataAccessResourceFailureException, IllegalStateException 
{
    return getSession(this.hibernateTemplate.isAllowCreate());
}
```

Which in turn calls to:

/**
 * Obtain a Hibernate Session, either from the current transaction or
 * a new one. The latter is only allowed if "allowCreate" is true.
 *.......

```
protected final Session getSession()
    throws DataAccessResourceFailureException, IllegalStateException {
return getSession(this.hibernateTemplate.isAllowCreate());
}
```

which ultimately calls to :

/** 
 * ....
 * @param allowCreate whether a non-transactional Session should be created
 * when no transactional Session can be found for the current thread
 * ....
 */

```
private static Session doGetSession(
    SessionFactory sessionFactory, Interceptor entityInterceptor,
SQLExceptionTranslator jdbcExceptionTranslator, boolean allowCreate)
```

Fundamentally, a Transaction:Session is tied 1:1 afaik, and the only way to run without a transaction is by using say JBoss which has a 'baked in' persistence layer which provides the transactionality for you (under the covers). Even if you call getQuery() after getSession() you still effectively have a transaction occuring as it's a JDBC/Hibernate connection.